# VS Code Python Syntax Highlighting

Tags: python, visual-studio, syntax

I installed VS Code and have been working on it for a while. I've been facing a small problem. The syntax highlighting for the python code is not working. I'm still not familiar with the setting or if I'm doing something wrong. I have attached an image of the problem.

[Heres an image that shows what's wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wNU1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your file as a .py so VScode knows it's looking a python file and can highlight the syntax accordingly.